# Clicking Buttons on a Website with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a google chrome extension that allows the user to press a button in the chrome extension menu and that causes a button on a selected webpage to be clicked.The problem I have currently is the syntax and code in my injector.js. It says unexpected token ; and unexpected token [. I would appreciate any help.
Here is my manifest.json:

```
    {
  "manifest_version":2,

  "name": "Button Click",
  "description": "Be able to press buttons",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Here is my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
    <head>
    <title>Fill</title>

    </script><script src="popup.js"></script>

    </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="htwo">Button presser</h2>
    <button id="press">Press Button</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

and my javascript:

```
window.onload=function(){
    if(document.getElementById("press")){
        document.getElementById("press").addEventListener('click',function(){
            document.getElementById("htwo").innerHTML="yay";
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                file:"injector.js"
            });
        });
    }
}
```

injector.js:

```
function pressButton(){
    var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName("button"),
    button[0].click();
}
pressButton();
```

By the way, the button I am trying to click is an input button  in which I inspect element, I get:
"(input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to cart" class="button")"
for some reason wont display
This button can be found here:
http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories/p840x2jsc/yks6zay73

Note: I know there were other people asking questions about the same topic, but the method that they used didn't work for me. 
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: The extension popup is a separate page with its own window, document, DOM. You need to run a content script in the tab, see the documentation and examples.

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: @wOxxOm I have edited my scripts and added a content script, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now it works. Install it and check it out.
To see how the extension works, you should be on this site (StackOverflow) and provide all these files and `icon.png`

> manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Button Click",  
    "description": "Be able to press buttons",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "browser_action": { 
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

> popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>Fill</title></head>  
    <body>
        <h2 id="htwo">Button presser</h2>
        <button id="press">Go to activity tab</button>  
        <script src="popup.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

> popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    // Gets all tabs that have the specified properties, or all tabs if no properties are specified (in our case we choose current active tab)
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // Injects JavaScript code into a page
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "utilities.js"});
    });
}
// adding listener to your button in popup window
document.getElementById('press').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

> utilities.js

```
/**
 * Gets the desired element on the client page and clicks on it
 */
function goToActivityTab() {
    var activityTab = document.getElementsByClassName("my-profile")[0];

    activityTab.click();
}

goToActivityTab();
```

For more information use these links

- [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)
- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)
- [Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) for beginners from Google

Comment: if I wanted to choose another button, how would I do it?

Comment: would I just find the class of the button and replace my-profile?

Comment: sorry to bother you so much, but I have a few questions

Comment: what does chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)  do? and also what does chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "utilities.js"}); this do.

Comment: @EdwardChen I've added comments and links that answer your questions

Comment: @EdwardChen If the answer satisfies you then you can mark it as correct

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I got it working by changing some of the javascript. Instead of using document.getElementsByClassName, I just used document.getElementsByName.Also you needed to add a window.onload function or else the program would start too early I think.Anayways, thanks so much for the help